# Argocd error while syncing : resource scheduling.k8s.io:PriorityClass is not permitted in project

Tags: argocd, argo-workflows

Argocd error while syncing application, unable to find any relevant documentation for same
any one has encountered it before and found any solution?

resource scheduling.k8s.io:PriorityClass is not permitted in project
another error:
resource storage.k8s.io:StorageClass is not permitted in project ns1-project-test

My manifest looks like below :

```
project: ns1-project-test
source:
  repoURL: 'git@ghe.exm-platform.com:<giturl....>'
  path: deploy-charts/
  targetRevision: 11.15.18
  helm:
    valueFiles:
      - values.yaml
    parameters:
      - name: services.tl_web_apps.nodeSelector
        value: aks
destination:
  server: 'https://66F5D9zzzzzzzF2D8B3-clusterURL.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com'
  namespace: ns1-namespace
syncPolicy: {}
```

Restart , delete and recreate deployment

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/970

~CLI command~

```
argocd proj  allow-cluster-resource <project-name> "*" "*"
```

~From Web UI~

Settings > Projects >

scroll down until you see "CLUSTER RESOURCE ALLOW LIST" then edit it to allow which is to be allowed

Answer (score 1):

Add `clusterResourceWhitelist` to the project

```
clusterResourceWhitelist:
  - group: "*"
    kind: "*"
```

more info:

https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in "argocd proj create" that did not create project properly (and no idea why). Project created manually (using argocd web-ui) did not impose limits on applications.

Probably bug in argocd (mine was v2.7.3+e7891b8), kubectl v1.25.4